# Show error if text has specific words or string in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Question`, which has the following fields:

- `question:text`
- `answer_1:text`
- `answer_2:text`
- `answer_3:text`
- `answer_4:text`

I want to disallow questions if they:

- Have the words `"not"` or `"except"` in the question,
- Have the words `"none of the above"` or `"all of the above"` in the answer fields,
- Start with `"true"`, `"false"`, `"yes"`, or `"no"` in the answer fields, or
- Have `"answer is"` in the answer itself.

Comment: You would better be looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion

Comment: `validates :question, exlusion: { in: ["not", "except"], message: "not allowed"}` doesn't help if field has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is how i solve my problem.

```
validate :check_question, :on => :create
DISALLOW_QUESTION = ["not", "except"]

def check_question 
  DISALLOW_QUESTION.each do |w|
      errors.add :question, "shouldn't have '#{w}'", if question.include? w
  end
end

validate :check_answer, :on => :create
DISALLOW_ANSWER = ["none of the above", "all of the above", "answer is"]
START_WITH = ['true', 'false', 'yes', 'no']

def check_answer 
  DISALLOW_ANSWER.each do |w|
    errors.add :answer_1, "shouldn't have '#{w}'" if answer_1.include? w
    errors.add :answer_2, "shouldn't have '#{w}'" if answer_2.include? w
    errors.add :answer_3, "shouldn't have '#{w}'" if answer_3.include? w
    errors.add :answer_4, "shouldn't have '#{w}'" if answer_4.include? w
  end
  START_WITH.each do |w|
    errors.add :answer_1, "can't start with '#{w}'" if answer_1.start_with? w
    errors.add :answer_2, "can't start with '#{w}'" if answer_2.start_with? w
    errors.add :answer_3, "can't start with '#{w}'" if answer_3.start_with? w
    errors.add :answer_4, "can't start with '#{w}'" if answer_4.start_with? w
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom validator in your model:

```
validate :check_words, :on => :create
NOT_ALLOWED_WORDS = ["not", "except"]

 def check_words 
  errors.add :question, "not allowed" unless (NOT_ALLOWED_WORDS - only_words_from_question) == NOT_ALLOWED_WORDS
end


def only_words_from_question
  self.question.split(/\W+/)
end
```

If there any "not allowed" word after create, in obj.errors.full_messages should be error "not allowed"  .

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I got down vote for this answer, so please can somebody tell me what's wrong here ? Anybody, please .

Answer (score 0):

If  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion  is not working for you, you may give regex a try:

In your controller, something like:

```
@question = Question.new(question_params)
if params[:question] =~  /not/ || params[:answer] =~ /all of the above/ || what-so-ever-conditions
   raise "not accepted"
else
   @question.save
end
```

However this is not a good solution, instead you should try what @pavan mentioned in his comment.